# JQuery Product Slider Errors

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to JQuery and am trying to create a product slider for my website. I was having some troubles so I made a basic version of it in this question. For some reason I am having no luck in getting it to work and have no idea why.

The three product boxes will animate as a section rather than individually, similar to this one https://smartslider3.com/product-carousel/. The animation will go from right to left when clicking the previous button and left to right when clicking the next button but I have just left it as slide up and slide down at the moment because I don't know the correct code for the animation. Touch swipe support would also be nice to have.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#slider-next-button").click(function(){

        var currentSlider = $(".active");
        var nextSlide = currentSlider.next();

        currentSlider.slideDown(2000);
        currentSlider.removeClass(active);
        nextSlide.slideUp(2000);
        nextSlide.slideUp(2000);
        })
});
;
```

```css
.content{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
.slider-section{
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 600px;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.slider-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 12fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
.slider-previous-button{
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slider-next-button{
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
    cursor: pointer;    
}
.slider-items{
    display: none;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
.slider-items.active{
    display: grid;
}

.slider-item{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slidertest.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slidertest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider-section">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="slider-container">
                <div class="slider-previous-button"><p></p></div>

                <div class="slider-items active">
                    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-next-button"><p></p></div>

                <div class="slider-items">
                    <div class="slider-item">4</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">5</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">6</div>
                </div>

                <div class="slider-items">
                    <div class="slider-item">7</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">8</div>
                    <div class="slider-item">9</div>
                </div>
                
                
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question does not state a problem.

Comment: Though just going off of the javascript, `slider-next-button` is a class, not an id.  `#` is for id selectors.  `.` is for class selectors